# How to pause game progress in KoA?

Tags: game-center, king-of-avalon-dragon-warfare

My KoA is connected through Game Center and I'd like to pause the current game progress for a month or few. The current risks leaving game on its own involves losing all troops, resources below storage level and having burned *Wall Defense* several times which can lead to a random teleport on the map, not to mention being kicked from the alliance and getting hundred of lose battle stats. I've missed anything, or that would be the worse scenario?

Are there any methods of pausing the game progress for longer period of time (e.g. due to travel) and minimalize the loses, or this is inevitable when leaving the game on its own? I'm aware of *Peace Shield*, but it can work only for maximum of few hours (like 2-12h).